Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY' from module '.../@types/react/canary"' type error, how do i fix?
When updating my code from react 18.2 to 18.3.1 I get this error:
Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY' from module '.../@types/react/canary"'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.

Seemingly random throughout the codebase and under no pattern I can find. Often erroring on the import statement or on the variable declaration. Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?
